# How can systemctl status show wrong Active value?

Tags: centos, systemd, systemctl

I'm using centos 8 OS. I have a service that starts tomcat on boot. And there was reported a bug that after update, that triggers reboot, tomcat haven't started (the system was rebooted). The result of

```
systemctl status {service.name}
```

was

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/{service.name}; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-10-02 18:42:21 EEST; 2 weeks 3 days ago
```

The problem here that it shows Active: 2 weeks 3 days ago, just after reboot. The issue was easily fixed by restarting service.

But I still wasn't able to reproduce it and understand how could it be possible.

I've tried to enable persistent storage for the systemd journal log by manually creating `/var/log/journal` folder
and `journalctl -u {service.name}`
showed logs before and after `-- Reboot --`
But the result of

```
systemctl status {service.name}
```

Still calculates time from last service start.

So does anybody know what could cause `Active: active (running)` to be outdated and show wrong status? (as service shouldn't show wrong time and active status). Thanks

Also Service startup time at the end of `systemctl status {service.name}` is from 2 weeks ago, so the whole log looks outdated

Updated
Service

```
[Unit]
Description=Start tomcat service
After=network-online.target snmpd.service
Wants=network-online.target
Conflicts=tomcat-debug.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/infrascale/stark-scripts/tomcat-start.sh
ExecStop=/opt/infrascale/stark-scripts/tomcat-stop.sh
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
Restart=always
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For now it looks like it's either human error and service status was taken before reboot or it could be some issue with systemd after kernel update we had from 4.18 to 5.14

Comment: Please add the service unit definition to the question. The type and configuration of the unit affects how systemd considers it to be 'running'. The 'Active' column reports that the service is running _since_ the indicated time; i,e it has been running for 2 weeks and 3 days when this output was generated.

Comment: The "status" output should have shown some PIDS for the process it thought it started. I wonder what those pids were.